# Check string in collection of objects using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON collection object like this

```
"Sections":[
    {"SectionName":"Dallas", ...}, 
    {"SectionName":"Austin", ...}, 
    {"SectionName":"Housto", ...}
]
```

If I want search for string "Austin" - how can I search directly without looping?

I am doing this but it is not straight.

```
 if (sections.length > 0) {
               $.each(sections, function(myObject) {
                   var sectionObject = sections[myObject];

                   if (Object.keys(sectionObject).length > 0 && sectionObject["SectionName"] != undefined) {
                    ...
                   }
               });
```

Comment: You will have loop through your array once. There is no other way here. Obviously, not considering an option to implement one of the search algorithms. But I think, that's not what you meant?

Comment: What's wrong with looping?

Comment: @Uzbekjon not true! You can do it manually, and then die internally when you're asked to change things.

Comment: @SterlingArcher can't disagree! The truth is yours :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return only objects which contains `"SectionName": "Austin"`

```js
var data = {
  "Sections": [{
    "SectionName": "Dallas",
  }, {
    "SectionName": "Austin",
  }, {
    "SectionName": "Housto",
  }]
}

data = data['Sections'].filter(el => el['SectionName'] == 'Austin');
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Mandatory lambda syntax because: `data = data['Sections'].filter(el => el['SectionName'] = 'Austin');`